# How to Write Test Case?

Tags: java

I'm currently struggling with making up a test case for methods for an assignment. The method is

```java
public ImageEntry(String pageAddress, String imgAddress)
{
  pageURL = pageAddress;
  imgURL = imgAddress;
}
```

Comment: hi, is this code Java or Javascript?

Comment: Hi, you should first ask yourself what is the purpose of the method (apparently here, a constructor for the object), then which behavior needs / require to have tests ensuring it works as expected. As it doesn't seem to have any "business" logic, there is not much to test honestly.

Comment: My opinion is that you don't need a test for this function. It's too simple.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming pageURL  and imgURL  are your class properties. You can write following cases:

1. ImageEntry("","imgaddress")  => and verify values are assigned correctly to class variables.
2. ImageEntry("pageAddress","")  => and verify values are assigned correctly class variables..
3. ImageEntry("","")  => and verify values are assigned correctly class variables.
4. ImageEntry("pageAddress","imgaddress")  => and verify values are assigned correctly class variables.